# What is this weapon on multiplayer on the Checkout map in Gears Of War 3?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I have only seen this twice in game and I have no idea what it is, or how to get it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a fire extinguisher.

You can get it using 
[this method](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nT6lkcUcnjk).

It doesn't actually shoot, but you can perform a special execution move with it.